# method will not return correct result

Tags: do-while

```
public static double infiniteSeries(int terms) {
    int i = 0;
    double result = 0;
    int n = 2;
    do{
        result += 1/n;
        i++;
        n *= 2;    
    } while (i < terms);
    return result;
}
```

here is the code that I have written so far.  the goal of the method is to return the sum of an infinite series 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8... + ... 1/n.  So if the user calls the method with an input of 1, the method should return .5 and if the user inputs 2, it shoudl return .75 and so on.  Any time I call this method it returns 0 no matter what terms I enter.  I tried changing result += 1/n; to result += n; and that returns the sum of the n values the way I would expect.  So it doesn't like the 1/n for some reason, but I have no idea why or how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `1/n`: Integer division. Try with `1.0/n`

Comment: you are using integer division in `1/n` so that `result` is accumulating only zeros, use something like `1./n`

Comment: wow I knew it had to be something simple.  Every fraction was being truncated to 0.  Thanks so much both of you!

Comment: I suggest you to add a tag to the programming language that you used to produce the example.